# Scraping no instagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scraping

Olá, gostaria de pedir uma ajuda, estou querendo fazer um scraping no Instagram para poder fazer analise de personas e extrair alguns dados como tags mais utilizadas pelas pessoas que seguem um determinado alguém, peguei um perfil x com alguns seguidores e conseguir fazer a extração de algumas informações.

A ideia é, conseguir pegar informações como tags utilizadas pelas pessoas que segue o determinado perfil para que possa identificar o que a pessoa gosta e traçar uma analise de persona, alguém poderia me ajudar por favor? abaixo o código que fiz ate o momento.

```
from urllib.error import URLError,HTTPError

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/martinhagondimoficial/followers/?hl=pt-br'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'}
try:
    req = Request(url, headers = headers)
    response = urlopen(req)
    print(response.read())

except HTTPError as e:
    print(e.status, e.reason)
    
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e.reason)
```

Comment: Única coisa que você fez até o momento foi obter uma páigna HTML. Agora você precisa operar em cima deste html.

Comment: no caso eu tenho que formatar para string para poder tratar os dados ?